# How I can read all nodes of external xml file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

How I can read all nodes of xml file in two state:
1- if I don't know the name of nodes.
2- if l know the name of nodes.

note: I can load and see the file, but I want the methods that make access to each nodes.
So I can do some function for each node.
Thanks.

```
var txml:XML;
var xmlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    xmlloader.load(new URLRequest("‫‫ole.xml"));
    xmlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);<br/>
function loaded(e:Event):void
    {   txml = new XML(xmlloader.data);
        var childNo:int; var namea: String; var sex:String;
        var id:int;
        namea= txml.@name; sex= txml.@sex;id = txml.@level;
        childNo= txml.@child;
        trace(childNo);
        trace(namea);
        trace(sex);
        trace(id);
        addmc(namea);}
```

Comment: can you post an example? can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to get the children.

`child` property will return XMLList and will let you search by child name

`children` just gives you all the children of specific node, no matter of the names

`descendants` will give even nested ones (can be searched by name)

There might be even more, you can look at the documentation, but these are the most common ones.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html